# Returning values from a call method to future object

Tags: java, future, java.util.concurrent

How can i return the iterated set values which are of type string from a call method to a future object.do i need to store the iterated vales in a array and return that array or can any one help me out

Comment: Please show us some (pseudo) code.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`Callable<List<String>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), submit it to an executor, which will return a `Future` whose [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) method will return a `List<String>`.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Callable<List<String>> task = new Callable<List<String>>() {
    public List<String> call() throws Exception {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        // populate list
        return list;
    }
};
Future<List<String>> future = executorService.submit(task);

// the list from above, returns once execution is complete
List<String> list = future.get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `submit()` method of `ExecutorService` which **returns** `Future` Object.